# How to find controls on OnRowEditing event of Gridview and Text associated with control?

Tags: asp.net

After finding controls (e.g Label,Image) I want to find the text value associated with all controls and finally assign that text value to textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `onRowEditing` Event

```
GridViewRow row = MyGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Label MyLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("MyLabel");
```

Assign the `lableText` value to the textboxes you want.

**Update 1:**

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
Label Mylabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("MyLabel");
```

`MyLable` is a Control ID which you have defined into the GridView on your .aspx page

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error occure

Answer (score 0):

For Row editing and updating you can use this...

```
protected void grdemployee_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{ 
      int id = Int32.Parse(grdemployee.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()); 
      TextBox txtname = (TextBox)grdemployee.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtname"); 
      grdemployee.EditIndex = -1; BindGridview(); 
}
```